# Bind values to jQuery UI select control from codebehind

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, jquery-ui

I am trying to bind values to a select control from codebehind. The select control is jquery UI multiselect.

The Code is:

The .aspx Page:

```
 <select id="countries" runat="server" class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="countries[]">
```

The .cs Page:

```
for(int i=0; i<=25;i++)
        {
            countries.Items.Add(i.ToString());
        }
```

When i run i'm getting the following parser error

Cannot create an object of type 'System.Boolean' from its string representation 'multiple' for the 'Multiple' property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the following code in the code behind Page_Load and it worked fine. tats it!!

```
languages.Attributes.Add("multiple", "multiple");
```

Comment: This didn't worked for me. It was showing runtime error as soon as I added runat="server" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try multiple="true". And also don't forget to close the select tag.

Comment: What's exactly not working? Can you post some sample code? Can you confirm that the Parser error that you were having is gone?

Comment: Now i'm not receiving the parser error. But the control is jQuery UI multiselect. Now the multiselect is not working. just its binding the values in a dropdown.

Comment: There are more than one multiselect jquery ui plugins. I don't know which one are you using. They will have different configuration options. So with no sample code I can't give you more help.

Comment: Maybe if you don't use a select with runat server and you can use ajax to get the options of the select and knockoutjs to bind them, you can put back multiple="multiple" and everything will work as expected.